# preg_replace() part of specific string to replace space to underscore

Tags: string, replace, preg-replace

```
$line1 = aaa bbb ccc ddd xxx yy y;

$line1 = preg_replace('/(\w.+) (\w.+) (\w.+) (\w.+) (\w.+) (\w.+\s+\w)/i', "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 + str_replace(' ','_', '$6')" , $line1);

echo $myLine1;
```

I hope the output is

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd xxx yy_y
```

but the result is

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd xxx + str_replace(' ','_', 'yy y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do another replacement on one of the capture groups, you can use preg_replace_callback. But in this case you can just match the spaces after the sixth occurrence and replace those with a single underscore.

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\w+\h+){5}` Repeat 5 times matching 1+ word chars and 1+ whitespace chars
- `\w+\K` Match 1+ word chars and forget what is matched so far
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars that will be replaced
- `(?=\w)` Assert a word char to the right

Also note that you don't need the `/i` for a case insensitive match as `\w` also matches lowercase chars.

```
$line1 = "aaa bbb ccc ddd xxx yy y";
$line1 = preg_replace('/^(?:\w+\h+){5}\w+\K\h+(?=\w)/', "_" , $line1);
echo $line1;
```

Output

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd xxx yy_y
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/nY20o) and a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MGmwVy/1).

Comment: thanks for reply, another question like that, a part of grep from url, i hope preg_replace only part of string, no include <td></td>, like that
```
$line1 =   <td style="width: 20px; color: red">O ne</td>;
```
and the output i hope is 
```
<td style="width: 20px; color: red">O_ne</td>;
```

Comment: @chi0001 For replacing spaces with an underscore in html, you could consider using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of a pure regex.